# Strange GIT remote url

Tags: git, network-protocols

```
git remote -vv
```

shows

```
origin  username@source:/var/git/repo.git (fetch)
origin  username@source:/var/git/repo.git (push)
```

What does it mean "source:" is it some kind of protocol?

One more thing it works without password but if use usual URL it requires password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works without password because it is an ssh url, and:

- your private key (in `~/.ssh/id_rsa`) is not passphrase protected (or it is and is still managed by the ssh-agent)
- your public key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) is registered in the source server at `~username/.ssh/authorize_keys` file.

> if I use usual URL it requires password.

If you are talking about an `http(s)://` url, then yes, it would require a username and a password.

Comment: Thank you, but alias 'source' and all other data in `~/.ssh/config`